# How to use bootstrap datetimepicker locale option properly

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I would like how to use bootstrap [datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/) [locale](https://github.com/moment/moment/tree/develop/locale) option properly.

Manual says

> locale Default: moment.locale() Accepts: string,
>   moment.local('locale') See momentjs for valid locales.
>
> You must include moment-with-locales.js or a local js file.

I would like to include `it.js`.

I have got this HTML but it doesn't apply custom language.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <%--<script src="/Scripts/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>--%>
    <script src="/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/it.js"></script>

</head>
```

So what  do I have to do?

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a how to use it.

$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'es'
});